# href of a php element

Tags: html, href

I am trying to learn html on the fly for a company that I am doing an internship for. They gave me some source code for web pages and I see something like:

```
href = SomeFileName.php
```

What is this line of code doing?

Is it connecting the pages or something?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Comment: If they only have `href = SomeFileName.php`, it does nothing.

Comment: Man, looks like people didn't like this question. I am trying to learn this stuff quickly and thought I could ask other people for help but I guess not.

Comment: you should have googled it first.. a simple google search would have provided a bunch of valid references that would have helped you...

Comment: You should provide a full example, you can look at https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-href.

Comment: For future reference, look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking a question that won't get the kind of reception this one did.

Comment: @Fabulous Thanks, I'll looks this over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The href attribute specifies the link's destination"

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

I strongly suggest you go over the tutorials [posted here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It's a link to another web page which is obviously a php page.

I guess it has something like

```
<a href="inter.php">Some page</a>
```

if it has ?something=1(or some numbers) then the php there is also a parameter that the called page can get from the clicked page.

Comment: You're assuming it is on an anchor element.

Comment: Well it can be anchor, link, area or base. I doubt they would be putting href=something.php out of nowhere as a text inside a web page.

Comment: Doubt all you want but until we know for sure you can't base your answers off of that.

Answer (score 0):

we have `<a></a>` which means a link text and when you click it ,it opens the link for you and we can use it like this code :-

```
    <a href="the_link_to_go">link_text</a>
```

and its an example:-

```
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040958/href-of-a-php-element">Hello</a>
```

[Hello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45040958/href-of-a-php-element)

Answer (score 0):

For your query .yes it is..this is a link to another page.

```
<a href=abcd.php>
```